# Trigger to prevent update of specific columns and rows in Mysql

Tags: mysql, triggers

I recentely posted a question about a trigger able to prevent update of specific tables, then I asked in comments a solution to prevent update of speficic columns and rows. I managed to write a trigger that prevents update of specific columns, but i still cant figure how to limit this to a specific number of rows. So I thought I should open a new question in order to give this solution to the ones that need it and also to have a reply on my other problem, meaning limit this trigger to a specific # of rows. The following trigger works for columns:

```
DELIMITER ;;

CREATE TRIGGER my_trigger BEFORE UPDATE ON test_table FOR EACH ROW
IF (NEW.price != OLD.price OR NEW.name != OLD.name) THEN
UPDATE UPDATE_OF_TABLE1_IS_NOT_ALLOWED SET value='Update not allowed!';
END IF;;

DELIMITER ;
```

Is there any way to choose the # of rows hit by this trigger? lets say i want to select an interval of rows or specific rows numbers... any hint? thanks a lot.

Comment: why nobody replies here? please help guys..

Comment: I don't really understand what you're asking. Is UPDATE_OF_TABLE1_IS_NOT_ALLOWED another table? That update statement will affect all rows of that table. If you want to restrict that UPDATE, then you need to put a where clause on it.